# "bogon" instead of "hostname" in MacOS File Sharing

Tags: macos, smb

[image]

As the above picture shows, when I turned on "File Sharing", MacOS tells me to access it by "smb://bogon", however, I think the correct item here should be "smb://<hostname>".

I've tested that I could not access my sharing folder through "smb://<hostname>", while "smb://<ip>" & "smb://<hostname>.local" works.

My environment is MacOS 14.0, MacBook Air with M2 chip.

Comment: And what is "bogon"? Isn't that the host name?

Comment: No. I’ve learned that “bogon” is a term in network.

Comment: Do you have the Mac's firewall turned on? [bogon def](https://www.apnic.net/manage-ip/apnic-services/registration-services/resource-quality-assurance/what-is-a-bogon-address/)